# Functional determinant inconsistency

Tags: determinant, matrix-calculus, differential-operators, functional-calculus

While trying to compute functional determinants, I faced an inconsistency, which I can exemplify by defining the following matrix

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} i \frac{d}{dt} + t & 0 \\\  0 & i \frac{d}{dt} - t\end{pmatrix} $$

Since $i \frac{d}{dt}$ is a hermitian operator, $M$ is a hermitian (infinite) matrix. Its determinant should be **real**.
Then I can compute its determinant, using the fact that this matrix is block diagonal, being careful that they do not commute:

$$ \det M = \det \left( \left(i \frac{d}{dt} + t \right) \left(i \frac{d}{dt} - t \right) \right) = \det \left(-\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2 - t^2 - i\right) $$

The commutation gave a factor $i$, and the operator $-\partial_t^2 - t^2 - i$ is no longer hermitian, and I believe the determinant is now a complex number.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: [Why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant) should your first equality hold more than the same one with the two factors flipped?

Comment: It also holds with the two factors flipped : det(diag(A,B)) = det(AB) = det(BA)

Comment: But then your $-i$ becomes $+i.$ So now, why should the two equalities of your comment hold?

Comment: Yes. But does this solve the problem ? It still looks like the determinant will not be real

Comment: I think the main problem is that you want to use identities det(diag(A,B)) = det(AB) = det(BA) which do not hold for the [functional determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant).

Comment: Then how to treat det(diag(A,B)) ? I am pretty sure it should hold, up to some infinities that I am used to cancel. But I get your point. Let $H$ be hermitian and $A$ be anti-hermitian, here we have $\det(H+A) = \det(H-A)$, but we also have $\det(H+A) = \det(H^\dagger - A^\dagger) = \det(H-A)^*$ so somehow $\det(H-A)$ should be real